# PHP Read Text File With Column Separated

Tags: php, readfile

I have a text file generated from our banking software which looks like this:

[image: The Text File Looks like this]

This is my code to print the text file contents line by line:

```
<?php
$myFile = "20151231.txt";


 $lines = file($myFile);
 foreach ($lines as $line_num) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($line_num)."<br>";
}
```

It prints like this:

[image: But it prints like this]

I just want each line that starts with:

```
====>
```

I want everything else deleted.

I tried a lot but failed to print lines with the columns separated as it looks in the text file image.

This is how I want each line to print:

```
====>0518 Intt on Consumer Loan         401010707                                   108,149.00
```

Your assistance regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you try with an If block inside foreach to check if the line begins with ===> ?

Comment: I posed my code above@Sasikumar

Comment: No, I didn't@dubes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print it as a table:

```
<?php
$myFile = "20151231.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);
echo '<table>';
foreach ($lines as $line_num) {
    if (strpos($line_num, '====>') !== false) {
        $str = trim(htmlspecialchars($line_num));
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . getColumnText("/====>\d+/", $str) .'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . getColumnText("/\s([a-zA-Z\s]+)/", $str) .'</td>';
        $secondCol = getColumnText("/\s([0-9]+)/", $str);
        echo '<td>' . $secondCol .'</td>';
        $thirdCol = end(explode(" ", $str));
        if (trim($secondCol) === $thirdCol) {
            echo '<td style="text-align:right">' . str_repeat(" ", 10) .'</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td style="text-align:right">' . str_repeat(" ", 10) . $thirdCol .'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>';

function getColumnText($pattern, $str) {
    preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
    return trim(current($matches));
}
```

Comment: It separates every word. But I wanted the columns to be separated. And, it doesn't delete the other lines I don't want

Comment: It's almost there. Can you also please separate the balances (0.00 or any other balances) just like you separated the first two columns? Here is the current outlook:  http://imgur.com/Si0AE9m

Comment: @Rashel I've update the code, I hope it will work for you

Comment: Excellent. It works. Just one problem.  When the 3rd column is empty, it takes the value of 2nd column to the 3rd column. Here is screenshot:  http://imgur.com/Ghz08M8

Comment: @Rashel I've updated the code, it is more complex now, but it should work

Comment: @OleksandrKaleniuk Hi, I face a similar problem with .rpt files I tried you solution above and it worked upto some extent for me. The issue with me is: I dont know the number of columns so it needs to be more dynamic. The files has some header data on every page which I dont need. Please help, I am in urgent need of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that with `strpos` or `regularexpression` and i am just writing code using `strpos`

```
<?php $myFile = "text.txt";


$lines = file($myFile);
 echo '<table cellspacing="20">';
 $linenum = 1;
 foreach ($lines as $line_num) {
    echo '<tr>';
    // check whether line conatain ====>, if you want to check starting of line then just put 0 instead of false in following condition
    if(strpos($line_num,'====>')!==false)
    {
        $texts= substr($line_num, strpos($line_num,'====>')+5);
        $textarr = explode(" ", $texts);
        echo '<td>'.$linenum.'</td>';
        foreach($textarr as $arr)
        {
            echo '<td>'.$arr.'</td>';
        }   
        $linenum++;

        //print_r($textarr);
        //echo htmlspecialchars($line_num)."<br>";

    }

}
echo '<table>';
```

Comment: i just update my answer... actually i forgot to have foreach

Comment: Yes, this now prints the lines I want and deleted everything else. But the columns are not separated. I mean, if there were gaps between the columns, it would be better. I mean, first the line number, then a little gap, then the description, then a little larger gap etc. would help it look better when printing

Comment: It now looks like this:  http://imgur.com/cwfU60F      If I don't find a better answer I will surely accept your answer as correct

Comment: i thats the result what you want

Comment: Is it possible to include seprator || between columns?

Comment: It should be in 4 columns - line number, description, gl codes and balance.   Please look at the last portion of my question on how I want the columns to look. But your current code splits the words too.

Comment: if you get data in "column1","column2","column3","column4" format then its possible